# Can I use JSPM without a transpiler?

Tags: jspm

I am using jspm 0.16.2.

I am using this [test project](https://github.com/caasjj/jspm-tut)

When I set the Transpiler to none: `transpiler: "none"`

I get an error `XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:53404/none.js`

If I set the transpiler to 'test' it gives the same error, except for it looks for `test.js`

Is this a bug with jspm?

I wanted to not use a transpiler, but use system.js to load AMD modules.

When I removed the transpiler option from config.js, then it tries to load Traceur.

I would like to not have a Transpiler running at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  If you use ES2015 features (e.g. ES2015 modules, `let`, etc.), then you need the transpiler.  If you write your code with no ES2015 features, then no transpiler will be loaded. You can check this by putting ES5 code in `main.js` and checking the Network tab of your debugger. `browser.js` will not be downloaded.

The string you put in for `transpiler` in `System.config` is literally the transpiler file itself.  In the case of `"babel"`, it is mapped to `npm:babel-core@5.8.3` (from `map` field) which when combined with the `path` field refers to `jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.8.3` and then in that directory, the file `.jspm.json` points the entry point to  `browser.js`, which is the client side transpiler file itself.

Whatever string you set `transpiler` to, jspm will set up `System` to  point to it (the path will just be the `baseURL` if you haven't mapped it) and fetch it. Of course it's not there for any arbitrary string such as `none` or `test`. The default, if you don't specify anything, as you've observed is `traceur`.

You do have the option of transpiling server side by doing `jspm bundle` if client side transipling is what you're trying to avoid.

For code that uses only ES5 and AMD, without transpiling, checkout the `no-transpile` branch of the above repo.  Note that `browser.js` is not downloaded even though `transpile` is still set to `"babel"`.

Comment: +1 for the detailed information.  I think I understand now what the situation.  I think what mislead me is that you can answer "No" to the Transpiler question when running jspm init, and it will insert "none" in config.js for the transpiler.

Comment: Yes, but then if your code has ES2015 features in it, `System` *will* try to transpile it anyway - with the `none` transpiler.  The safe thing to do, if you want to make certain there is no transpilation, is to set that field to any invalid string (such as `none`) and then write your code with straight ES5.  That way, you'll error out if any ES2015 code sneaks in, e.g. via some module you imported.

Comment: OK, I get it now.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Why bundle doesn't transpile code during bundling, so we can use es6 and no transpiler in the browser?

Comment: @rofrol Sure it does. See my updated instructions in the `master` branch of the test project repo OP mentions.

Comment: Your instructions mention es5. I want to use es6, transpile it during bundling and don't load tracer into the browser

Comment: Please look at the repo 'master' branch more carefully.  'main.js' is an ES6  module.  If you follow the exact instructions, you will get a single transpired 'bundle.js' downloaded to the browser and no transpiler downloaded.

Comment: Hi @caasjj, your repo cleared a lot of things up for me with regard to transpiling and jspm builds, thank you. I noticed that when I try and asynchronously load a module in the main bundle, the ES6 module is effectively fetched with `System.import()`.  This must mean that some transpiling capabilities are included. Also, is there a method by which I can async load ES5 modules with System.import? Explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018965/using-jspm-to-load-async-es5-modules-in-production