# Using SystemJS/jspm to load async, es5 modules in production

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I want to be able to asynchronously load dependencies using `System.import()`, but without having to transpile ES6 to ES5 during production runtime. I want these modules to be transpiled into separate, ES5 modules that are fetched only when needed. I don't want them to be a part of the main bundle.

**Dev Workflow**

The modules are effectively loading during my production build which is actually worrisome because I don't want to include any dependencies that allow for transpilation.

I have a workflow where I'm using `jspm bundle` and `jspm unbundle` to toggle between development and production configurations. In my development environment, I'm including the following scripts:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('src/main');
</script>
```

**Production Workflow**

In production, I'm using `jspm bundle --inject` to inject the `bundles` option into `System.config`. This effectively loads only the necessary files:

```
system.js
config.js
main.bundle.js
```

When I try to load a module asynchronously with `System.import()` during production, it loads fine, which means that transpilation is happening in the browser during production.

---

**Questions**

1. I can easily build each of my modules into AMD, but how can I still
   asynchronously and separately fetch them using `System.import()`?
2. I also want to make sure to include as little browser overhead as
   possible, which means not including any scripts that perform
   transpilation. Is there a way to include `system.js` that does not
   have transpile capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1

System.import() is used for loading modules. Modules are essential .js files that export something such as a function or an Object or a Class.

If you organise your code into separate files then you can load them either in the head of another file using ..

```
import * as YM from 'YourModuleFile';
```

this would make YM accessible in the entire file.

Or if you want YM loaded on a button click instead ..

```
element.onclick = function() {
    System.import('YourModuleFile').then(function(YM) {
        // YM accessible here
    })
}
```

So the important thing becomes organising your code well inside files / modules.

You then might use an npm task runner such as gulp to compress the files, etc.

Of course, you will need to enter some mappings inside your systemjs.config.js file such as ..

```
'YourModuleFile': '/path/to/your/module/file.js'
```

So that SystemJS can find it.

Answer 2

JSPM has tranpile capabilities, I'm not sure SystemJS does.

Ensure JSPM (or your tool of choice) transpiles your files. Then point SystemJS to the transpiled files.