# Reduce Size of Large, React based Single Page Application's Browserify Bundle File

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I am building a reactjs application using gulp and Browserify. I have used material-ui components in my application. There are 8 pages in my application using different components.

The build.js created by Browserify is 4mb in size. I want to reduce its size. I have searched and learned a little about the lazy loading design pattern. But I am confused how it should be used to make the size smaller of my application?

I am also using react router in my application so there are 8 routes defined. I have an idea that we can lazy load the files required for each route, but how could that be done in react?

P.S : I would have loved to share some code, but i don't understand what kind of code will be required for such a question.

Comment: First step: `minify` the code with [Uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), then use something like [collapser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-collapser) to reduce duplicate path strings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that your javascript contains source maps.  Source maps can easily increase the size of your code by an order of magnitude.   Try taking a look at your compiled JS file and if you see large random strings that look something like this:

dlfheihfgrewifjwe;iofgrewfwejroifnekw.nfoeiquf0eqf;oiwehjfkl;qwejfio;qeo;f;qoihfi;qejhfkjqwehj

then you are including source maps in your compiled Js.

Check your browserify config to make sure that you are not compiling with source maps.